# Options for long term storage of helium?

Tags: safety, noble-gases

Specifically, if I wanted to purchase a large amounts of helium, what are my options for purchasing helium in a state that is suitable for long term storage?

It's my understanding that if I were to buy helium in bulk it would be shipped cold, as a liquid.  Keeping helium in liquid form for 10-20+ years would involve a lot of serious refrigeration.

Are there other reasonable options for bulk, long term storage?

This may not seem like much of a "chemistry" question but since this is used in chemical sciences, I assume this is a need that some may be aware and may have a good answer since this is an elemental material that some may use on a very common basis.

Comment: Steel baloon and helium in gaseous form may be an option, if you have enough space for it. Definitely, it will take much space, but it is still an option. Another option is cryogenic storage, but to my knowledge it is quite complex for liquid helium and requires regular income of liquid nitrogen.

Comment: Just out of sheer curiosity, what is the helium for?

Comment: Richard Terrett: Retirement. ;)

Comment: You should read this page (http://www.linde-kryotechnik.ch/1259/1260/1308/1310.asp) and the pdfs at the bottom. How big is your underground laboratory?

Comment: @RLH - I had my suspicions. Personally, I would go for a less... _volatile_ investment. *ba-dum-tish*

Comment: Well, I wouldn't invest a significant portion of my worth in Helium but there have been doom-and-gloom reports for quite a while regarding the coming scarcity of helium. I've tried to do a bit of research but other than pushing for legislation to change the market, no one is doing anything about the problem. I would imagine the major barrier to stockpiling is probably the long term cost of storing enough Helium for 20+ years. If you have to refrigerate it for that long, it's going to cost a fortune. If you can store it in strong, highly compressed tanks as a gas, then it might be worth it.

Comment: You want buy creeper helium, and after some years get a lot of money selling on higher price? :) The money inflation will eat all profit. Liquid helium is hard to obtain and quite extremely impossible to storage long-term. http://www.janis.com/4KCCR_Home_KeySupplier.aspx But this helium is used to make high magnetic field. Just for storing it will be huge energy waste. I totally agree with pat - using simple high pressure tanks/cylinders is the best option.

Comment: It's 2019.  I never found a way to store helium for the long-term.  I wish I had.

Answer (score 4):

In my experience, for small quantities in laboratories helium usually comes compressed in cylinders. Except possibly in the case that you require extremely high purity, I don't see why helium couldn't be stored for long periods in this form, it would be relatively safe and would avoid the need for refrigeration.

I don't know what sort of quantities you are thinking about, but it seems that you can get big cylinders. For example the largest cyclinder size available from BOC gases, a British company, is 194.7 $m^3$ filled to a pressure of 300 $bar$ ([source: BOC website](http://www.boconline.co.uk/en/products-and-supply/speciality-gas/pure-gases/pure-gases.html)).

Comment: Compressed helium stored in cylinders is what I would suggest too. If you have a large quantity, [buy a natural geologic gas storage formation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Helium_Reserve)…

Answer (score 0):

helium will diffuse through steel over time.
there is no way known to man to keep it indefinitely unless its cooled.
nitrogen and argon though can be stored in bottle over a decade or two.
maybe a ref or two might be in order

Measurement of Helium
Diffusion in Metals
https://www.energy.gov/sites/prod/files/2019/06/f63/Measurement-of-Helium-Diffusion-in-Metals.pdf

DIFFUSION AND AGGLOMERATION
OF HELIUM IN STAINLESS STEEL
https://inis.iaea.org/collection/NCLCollectionStore/_Public/38/111/38111384.pdf

So the simple truth is every balloon is one less person with an MRI.
It is mined from the planet and it is not being replaced at the rate its being taken at.
Try not to use helium if you can guys please.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/163593)